# Why does dollar sign is needed between echo and "SENTENCE"

Tags: centos, echo

I found `echo $"<SENTENCE>"` like `echo $"Starting $prog: "` in /etc/init.d/* scripts.

I tested with terminal on my CentOS6.7 server. However I can not understand why "$" is needed before `"<SENTENCE>"`.

```
$ prog=sample_process
$ echo $"Starting $prog: "
Starting test_process:
$ echo "Starting $prog: "
Starting test_process:
```

**[Question]**
Why does '$' is needed between `echo` and "SENTENCE"? In my opinion, both `echo $"Starting $prog: "` and `echo "Starting $prog: "` are same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`man bash`, under QUOTING:

> A double-quoted string preceded by a dollar sign (`$"string"`) will cause
>          the  string  to  be translated according to the current locale.  If the
>          current locale is C or POSIX, the  dollar  sign  is  ignored.   If  the
>          string is translated and replaced, the replacement is double-quoted.

EDIT: [tutorial](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-localization-with-echo-command/).